# Electrum-personal-server isn't seeing any historical transactions; using a Trezor

Tags: wallet, electrum, full-node

I followed the instructions in the Electrum Personal Server guide. I know that the transactions are there because I checked `wallet.trezor.io`. But none are showing up in Electrum. I have run `--rescan`. I have `bitcoind` running in the background as a full node.

The instructions are here: https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server

Answer (score 2):

It's the wallet type. There are three address types: legacy, p2sh-segwit and segwit. Choose the right one or your transaction history will be empty.